# How do i execute a runnable that has to be defined in a xml file

Tags: android

I have a menu structure defined in a library, it uses preferenceActivity and such. 
What i want is to have a menu defined in a library and in the final apps i just want to create a xml file that says what menu items i have and what to do when someone hits the item.

I know that i can define an intent and fire it by the menu but that seems very bulky and is not what i am looking for. I would like to define a runnable somewhere in the final app and refer to it via xml and the library-menu should be able to read the xml and run the runnable.

Is it possible at all ?

Edit:
Here is what i need:
There is a menu with all its things defined in a library. When implemented, it should do things that are defined in a .xml file in the target application. I can set preferences with ease and fire intents. But how to i execute a runnable this way ? if i set up a broadcastlistener that listens for intents, its not exactly smooth. 
The only way it is working atm (old library) is that the menu inside the library needs to know every code that could be executed through menu. And thats overkill.

Comment: runnable defined in the xml? no, no such option

Comment: I read your question many times and I'm not understanding what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i did it.

In my attrs.xml (inside the library) i defined the following attribute

```
<attr name="runnable" format="string" />
```

Then i define a specific menu in every app with entries like

```
<com.company.library.menu.CustomPref
    android:title="@string/mytitle"
    android:icon ="@drawable/icon"
    custom:runnable="com.company.someapp.somefolder.MyRunnable" />
```

In my `class CustomPref extends Preference`

```
@Override
protected void onClick() {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(runnable_string_from_xml);

        // check if it's a Runnable

        Object o = clazz.newInstance();

        if(o instanceof Runnable) {
            Runnable r = (Runnable) o;
            myPrefActivity.runOnUiThread(r);
        }
    } catch () //...
```

Now i can define files/classes that implement Runnable inside my final app(s) and create menues that will execute those runnables even tho the menu is created in the library and has no clue what classes will be there at runtime.

All menues are built from xml (requirement in this case)